# JTable cell render based on content

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I design a system by Java Swing. I have a tablet called sick and this tablet has a column called status which has two values,one is open and another is closed values. When the value of the column is open I want to change color to blue and when it is closed I want to change color to red (when the information is selected from the database).

Comment: What are you asking for? How are we supposed to answer this?

Comment: It seems like you already know what you need to do. Write a Renderer and check the value and adjust the background color based on value. What is your question?

Comment: Start with [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). Try something, fail and a few times, try some other things.  If you're still having trouble, post a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

What it appears you are looking to do is a form of Conditional Formatting against one or more specific cells within a JTable. This can be done by overriding the JTable's [prepareRenderer()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer(javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int)) method with a custom Prepare Renderer method:

[image]

Here is a runnable code example that displays the above example form image:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;


public class JTablePrepareRendererExample {

    // Age Group colors
    Color ageGroup1Color = Color.decode("#FCF3CF");    // Light Yellow
    Color ageGroup2Color = Color.decode("#EBDEF0");    // Light Magenta
    Color ageGroup3Color = Color.decode("#D4EFDF");    // Light Green
    Color ageGroup4Color = Color.decode("#FAD7A0");    // Light Orange
    Color ageGroup5Color = Color.decode("#D4AC0D");    // Gold
    Color ageGroup6Color = Color.decode("#566573");    // Dark Gray

    // Status Group Colors
    Color openColor = Color.decode("#D4E6F1");         // Light Red
    Color closeColor = Color.decode("#FADBD8");        // Light Blue

    // Row Selection Color
    Color selection = Color.decode("#7FB3D5");         // A lighter Blue 

    // Table Default Colors
    Color cellsOrigBackColor = new JTable().getBackground();
    Color cellsOrigForeColor = new JTable().getForeground();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // So we don't need statics...
        new JTablePrepareRendererExample().startDemo(args);
    }

    private void startDemo(String[] args) {
        initializeForm();
    }

    private void initializeForm() {
        // Create a JFrame Form (with title).
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Conditional Formatting");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  // Set its' Close Operation
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);  // Set that form will be on top of all other applications.
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 250));     // Set the form size.
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  // Set the form to utilize the Border Layout Manager.

        // Table Column Names
        Object[] columnNames = {"Name", "Age", "Alive", "Case Status"};

        // Table Data...
        Object data[][] = {
            {"Tracey Johnson", 24, "Yes", "Unknown"},
            {"Frank Thetank", 108, "Barely", "Closed"},
            {"Denis Therman", 41, "Yes", "Open"},
            {"Joe Blow", 60, "Yes", "Unknown"},
            {"Fred Flintston", "@1", "No", "Closed"},
            {"John Doe", 73, "Yes", "Open"},
            {"James Brown", 87, "No", "Closed"} };

        // Create a JTable Model and fill the table model with the above Object data...
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        // Declare a JTable and set the Table Model to that table.
        JTable table = new JTable(model) {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            // Here is where all the cell formatting is done in this example
            @Override
            public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                Color cellBackColor = cellsOrigBackColor;  // Original Cells Backgound color.
                Color cellForeColor = cellsOrigForeColor;  // Original Cells Foregound (text) color.

                /* Acquire the current cell component being Rendered.
                   ALL cells get Rendered.            */
                JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, columnIndex);

                // The 'Age' Field Color Conditions...
                // ===================================
                // Get the 'Age' field value and convert to integer.
                if (columnIndex == 1) {
                    String sAge = getValueAt(rowIndex, 1).toString();
                    int age = -1; // Age Default.
                    /* Make sure the data value in the current Age cell 
                       being rendered is indeed a string representation 
                       of a Integer (int) numerical value.           */
                    if (sAge.matches("\\d+")) {
                        // Convert the table cell value to Integer
                        age = Integer.parseInt(sAge);
                    }
                    else {
                        /* If it's not a Integer type value then indicate
                           ERROR in cell and highlight RED  */
                        cellBackColor = Color.RED;
                        component.setBackground(cellBackColor);
                        cellForeColor = properTextColor(cellBackColor);
                        component.setForeground(cellForeColor);
                        model.setValueAt("** ERROR **", rowIndex, 1);
                        return component;
                    }

                    if (age <= 25) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup1Color;
                    }
                    else if (age >= 26 && age <= 45) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup2Color;
                    }
                    else if (age >= 46 && age <= 65) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup3Color;
                    }
                    else if (age >= 66 && age <= 80) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup4Color;
                    }
                    else if (age >= 81 && age <= 95) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup5Color;
                    }
                    else if (age > 95) {
                        cellBackColor = ageGroup6Color;
                    }
                    else {
                        cellBackColor = cellsOrigBackColor;
                    }
                }

                // The 'Status' Field Color Conditions...
                // ======================================
                // Get the 'Status' field value
                String status = getValueAt(rowIndex, 3).toString();
                if (columnIndex == 3) {
                    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("closed")) {
                        cellBackColor = closeColor;
                    }
                    else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("open")) {
                        cellBackColor = openColor;
                    }
                    else {
                        cellBackColor = cellsOrigBackColor;
                    }
                }

                /* Set Age cell's determined Background color 
                   based on any of the particular conditions 
                  stipulated above.               */
                component.setBackground(cellBackColor);
                /* Set cell's Text (foreground) Color based on 
                   color and brightness of Cell's Background 
                   color.           */
                cellForeColor = properTextColor(cellBackColor); // Helper method
                component.setForeground(cellForeColor);

                // If a row is selected, maintain the conditional formatting...
                if (isRowSelected(rowIndex)) {
                    component.setBackground(selection);
                } else {
                    component.setBackground(cellBackColor);
                }
                return component;
            }
        };

        /* Set the table size, columns not selectable, 
           rows selectable via single selection   */
        table.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
        table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

        /* Create a JScrollPane, set its size to Table and 
           add the Table to the JScrollPane ViewPort.   */
        JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
        sp.setPreferredSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        sp.getViewport().add(table);

        // Create a JPanel to hold JScrollPane (and JTable)
        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.add(sp);   // Add ScrollPane to JPanel

        /* Create another JPanel to hold a JLabel 
           and the JButtons 'Add' and 'Close'  */
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        // Set this JPanel to utilize a 'Flow Layout Manager'
        buttonsPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); // Center any compnents in panel.

        // Create a JLabel. Shown how to utilize HTML here for a JLabel.
        JLabel doLabel = new JLabel("<html><pre><font color=blue>"
                + "Select a row and edit a cell.      </font></pre>"
                + "</html>");

        // Create the 'Add' JButton.
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add"); 
        addButton.setToolTipText(" Add a Table Row ");  // Set a ToolTip for 'Add' Button.
        // Apply an Action Listener to 'Add' Button.  
        addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                model.addRow(new Object[]{"", "0", "", ""});
            }
        }); 

        // Create the 'Close' JButton.
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.setToolTipText(" Close Application ");  // Set a ToolTip for 'Close' Button.
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }); // Apply an Action Listener to 'Close' Button.

        buttonsPanel.add(doLabel);      // Add JLabel to Buttons JPanel.
        buttonsPanel.add(addButton);    // Add 'Add' JButton to Buttons JPanel.
        buttonsPanel.add(closeButton);  // Add 'Close' JButton to Buttons JPanel.

        frame.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);   // Add The Table JPanel to top of JFrame Form.
        frame.add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // Add The Buttons JPanel to bottom of JFrame Form.

        frame.pack();   // Pack the components on JFrame.
        frame.setVisible(true); // Make the JFrame form visible.
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  // Make sure JFrame displays at center Screen.
    }

    /**
     * Returns either the Color WHITE or the Color BLACK dependent upon the
     * brightness of what the supplied background color might be. If the
     * background color is too dark then WHITE is returned. If the background
     * color is too bright then BLACK is returned.<br><br>
     *
     * @param currentBackgroundColor (Color Object) The background color text
     *                               will reside on.<br>
     *
     * @return (Color Object) The color WHITE or the Color BLACK.
     */
    public static Color properTextColor(Color currentBackgroundColor) {
        double L; // Holds the brightness value for the supplied color
        Color determinedColor;  // Default

        // Calculate color brightness from supplied color.
        int r = currentBackgroundColor.getRed();
        int g = currentBackgroundColor.getGreen();
        int b = currentBackgroundColor.getBlue();
        L = (int) Math.sqrt((r * r * .241) + (g * g * .691) + (b * b * .068));

        // Return the required text color to suit the 
        // supplied background color.
        if (L > 129) {
            determinedColor = Color.decode("#000000");  // White
        }
        else {
            determinedColor = Color.decode("#FFFFFF");  // Black
        }
        return determinedColor;
    }

}
```

In the above example there are two specific data columns that have specific conditions checked on each column cell, the **Age** column and the **Case Status** column.

In the **Age** column, a specific age range determines the cell background color that will be displayed. You will notice that for the **Fred Flintston** row, the **age** value holds a ERROR message (highlighted in red) instead of a age value. If you look in the Object data array values you will see that the value supplied there (**"@1"**) for Age is not a proper integer value. This yet another condition which is checked within the Renderer. The colors used for this column are declared within the class as member variables.

The **Case Status** Table column checks for three specific conditions:

1. If cell value contains a string value of "Open" then that cells
   background color will be a **light red**.
2. If cell value contains a string value of "Closed" then that cells
       background color will be a **light blue**.
3. If a *cell value is anything other than* "Open" or "Closed" then that
   cells background color will be the original cell background color.

Even the Row Selection color is modified within this custom Renderer to a lighter, more comfortable blue (well, in my opinion).

Because the possibility of background color change is available so too must be the capability to change the text (cell foreground) color so that it will be legible within certain colors. By default the JTable cell text color is black, this makes text extremely hard to read if the cell's background color is changed to dark gray or even dark red. White text would be a better choice. For this reason I have also included a helper method named **properTextColor()** that will automatically supply a text color (either White or Black) that would be the easiest to see dependent upon the Background color supplied to the method. You can see this at work within the example application image provided specifically in **Age** column cells (rows: "Frank Thetank" and "Fred Flintston").